# How to get uBoot to work with a squashfs / What is FDT in uBoot?

Tags: command-line, embedded-linux, bootloader, u-boot

I set-up the Kamikaze toolchain (from [openwrt](http://www.openwrt.org)), and compiled Linux 2.6.30.x kernel for an [AMCC PPC405ex kilauea](http://www.appliedmicro.com/MyAMCC/jsp/public/productDetail/product_detail.jsp?productID=PPC405EX) reference board. However, for some reason I am doing something wrong in uBoot, as I am not able to run the kernel from an squashfs image. The image loads fine over tftp and uncompresses, but the console output does not start.

I haven't changed the Linux kernel command line and it looks just fine (`console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/mtdblock`). I am also a bit puzzled what is **fdt** in uBoot?

I am not entirely certain if this really belongs on stackoverflow, but then again this is not really a superuser.com question either (and because this has to do with a development environment it definitely is *programming related*, even though not exactly a programming question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this myself, I am *not* supposed to use the `openwrt-boardname-squashfs.img` but instaed I must use the `openwrt-architecture-uImage` image, containing just the kernel, take the `root.squashfs` and `openwrt-boardname.dtb` from the `build_dir` as they are not copied in the `bin/` directory.

after that, these commands will bring up the board correctly:

```
tftp 0xfc1e0000 openwrt-kilauea.dtb
tftp 0x400000 openwrt-ppc40x-uImage
tftp 0x200000 root.squashfs
setenv bootargs 'console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/mtdblock2 rw'
bootm 0x400000 - 0xfc1e0000
```

there probably is an easier way, but I haven't figured out how to 'repartition' the mtd so I wouldn't have to initially load the kernel image to `user` space in the memory.